# Integrate $\int \dfrac{e^x}{1+\cos x}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^x}{1+\cos x}dx$

My Effort;
I couldn't nothing.

Comment: Hint: Use half angle formula of cos x to get sec square then integrate by parts.

Comment: still can I use that hint?

Comment: This cannot be solved with elementary means: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(e%5Ex)%2F(1%2Bcos+x)+dx

Comment: $\dfrac{e^x}{1+cosx}dx=\dfrac{e^x}{2 cos^2(x/2)}dx=\dfrac{e^xsec^2(x/2)}{2}$   I tried this ,might be wrong ,someone may point it out if that is wrong.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Are you sure that the function in the denominator is $\cos x$ (and not e.g. $\cosh x$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\cos(x)=\dfrac{1-\tan^2(x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}$ and then it's all easy.

Comment: Sorry ,ops I did mistake I mean $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{e^x}{1+cosx}dx$

Comment: Okay if I get I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1\iff1+\cos2A=?$$

Now $\dfrac{d\tan(ax)}{dx}=a\sec^2(ax)$

Comment: Sorry ,ops I did mistake I mean $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{e^x}{1+cosx}dx$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{1+\cos x}=\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2x}$$

and now split the integral in two almost immediate ones.

Comment: ops I did mistake I mean $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{e^x}{1+cosx}dx$

Comment: @fotonyiyenadam Wow, a "little" mistake you did...I'd advice you to post **another** question and leave this as it is. It is nonsensical, and also a little rude, to change so radically your question and after several hours many people already made an effort to help you and post answers.